# MysqlDump with ignore errors

Tags: mysqldump, backup

I'm helping a friend to backup his database, but I can't get it right doing standard `mysqldump` process, when I try to use `mysqlcheck`, I sort the result: http://pastie.org/9748430

'___') It's seriously scary..

Ok, now the question, how to make mysqldump ignore the error and continue backup till it's complete?

last error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `xxx`': Table '.\mydb1\xxx' is marked as crashed and should be repaired (145)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, using this flag:

```
--skip-lock-tables -f
```

The schema still can't be exported correctly, except by using `phpmyadmin`

Comment: Your database seems to be mostly corrupted. I recommend you to delete all your table files and reimport them. I also recommend you to use InnoDB instead of MyISAM to avoid further corruption problems in the future.

Comment: yes, it's wasn't me who design/administrate the server.. and yes, he is using `MyISAM` since 2011